# ionic 2 with restAPI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic2 with rest API.

Here is my code

```
let body={
      O_NUMBER: "",
      CART_ID: "",
      S_ID: "",
      PRODUCTS:"",
      BILLING: "string",
      SHIPPING: "",
      PAYMENT: {
        "TYPE": "",
        "SUBTOTAL": "",
        "TAX_TOTAL": "",
        "TOTAL_AMOUNT": "",
        "TRANSACTION_ID": ""
      },
      DATE: "",
      STATUS: "",
      customerId: ""
    }
let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

     let options = new RequestOptions({         
        method: "POST",
        body: body,        
        headers: headers });
     return this.http.get(this.url + 'orders?access_token='+ this.Id+body,options);
```

But body values passed into an object.

How can I fix this issue.

Here is my output.

```
http://35.154.116.133:3000/api/orders?access_token=ZzhdW7cLdocFyOtPsmMMWH4Q60fHs4zzJ1uYDOPTSWDxx83792pfJvLbRfSKbtRn[object%20Object]
```

also i tried to http.post.

But not work.

Comment: you're mixing up get and post. you activly build the url, that's why you see [object%20Object]

Answer (score 0):

To pass values as a part of the query string use `URLSearchParams` class from the `@angular/http`:

```
import { Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http'

let body = { ... };

let queryParams = new URLSearchParams();

// Add AccessToken to query parameters.
queryParams.set('access_token', this.Id);

// Add all the elements of the 'body' object to query parameters.
for (let key in body) {
  if (body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    queryParams.set(key, body[key]);
  }
}

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

let options = new RequestOptions({
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers,
  params: queryParams
});

return this.http.get(this.url + 'orders', options);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I am getting this err.Cannot find name params.

Comment: No.Its not working I am getting another err he `order` instance is not valid. Details: `O_NUMBER` can't be blank (value: undefined);...But i passed all values.

Comment: @vaishuani I edited the answer, but I guess there will be a problem with the nested object inside of your JSON. Simple for loop I did in example won't do it. Have you tried passing all the values manually by using `queryParams.set(key, value);` for each?